# How could Madara use Kamui as the Ten-Tails Jinchuriki while Obito himself couldn't?

Tags: naruto

Obito explained that while we was the Ten-Tails Jinchuriki, he could not use Kamui, his Mangekyo Sharingan's unique ability. He was later able to use it when the Ten-Tails was extracted from him, and while we was trying to take the Tailed Beasts from Madara and while fighting Kaguya Otsutsuki.

The same is explained in the Naruto wiki:

> There is really something wrong on how Kamui interacts with Juubi's Jinchuriki body. **Way back in Chapter 643, it was noted that by being the ten-tails jinchuriki, Obito can no longer use his Kamui** to travel through his pocket dimension nor to become intangible.

<sup>(emphasis my own)</sup>

But while Madara was on his goal to retrieve his other Rinnegan which Obito hid, he was able to use Kamui to get to Obito's pocket dimension and take his Rinnegan back. But he did all of this while he was the Jinchuriki of Ten-Tails.

It's shown *[in this YouTube video](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DiM_-tfPxrT0&ved=2ahUKEwjM6_3Px8_xAhUVk2oFHblgBn0QwqsBMAF6BAgKEAE&usg=AOvVaw0eayVBEwOTOQdlHkPJte5r)* that Madara uses Kamui to retrieve his Rinnegan.

To sum it up, Obito, the original owner of the Kamui ability was not able to use the ability while he was Ten-Tails Jinchuriki. However, while Madara was Ten-Tails Jinchuriki, he used Kamui, retrieved his Rinnegan, then came back to the actual world.

Why did this happen? Is it ever explained?

Comment: This is a good question. I'll note I was a little confused at how Madara was using Kamui at all, because you didn't mention that Madara took Kakashi's Sharingan. I've forgotten a lot of the specifics of events, I suppose.

Comment: Not sure if any answers are authoritative, but same question here, with some references: https://www.quora.com/Why-couldn-t-Obito-use-Kamui-when-he-was-the-Ten-Tails-Jinchuriki-He-still-had-his-Mangekyo-Sharingan and here: https://naruto.fandom.com/f/p/2264620509167758924

Comment: [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/Naruto/comments/kr9c71/how_did_madara_use_kamui_as_the_ten_tails/) Reddit thread discussed it as well. The users there give some decent plausible answers, it all boils down to "plot armor"

Comment: @ShayminGratitude Sorry for the ***incredibly*** late response, but yeah, that's why I attached the YouTube video, since I couldn't find the manga chapter & panel where it happens.